# AlarmManager doesn't update push notification time (hours and minutes) after the first notification sent

Tags: android, push-notification, alarmmanager

I'm using an AlarmManager to repeat a Push Notification Service every 60 seconds. So, every 60 seconds, the service sends a new push notification, but with the wrong time (hours and minutes): for example, if the service starts at 00:39, it sends a push notification with time=00:39; then, after 60 seconds (so when the clock is on 00:40), the service sends a new push notification with the same time of the first notification, and it will send push notification with the same time "forever". 
 You can see how the service behaves in this image
[image]

Here my code ("ServicesDemo.java" calls the service named "MyService.java"): 
 **ServicesDemo.java**

```
public class ServicesDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  Button buttonStart, buttonStop;
  AlarmManager alarmManager;
  PendingIntent pendingIntent;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
    buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);

    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  public void onClick(View src) {
    switch (src.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonStart:
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ServicesDemo.this , MyService.class);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ServicesDemo.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000 , pendingIntent);  //set repeating every 60 seconds
      break;
    case R.id.buttonStop:
      alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    NotificationManager NM;
    Notification notify;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        NM=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notify=new Notification(android.R.drawable.
                stat_notify_more,"Notification",System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(),0, new Intent(),0);
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notify.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),"Title","Body",pending);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        NM.notify(0, notify);
    }
}
```

I got frustrated about it. Does anyone knows how to fix this problem? Every help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This link might help: [Managing Android Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: This helped me alot! Thank you so much, I will post the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [FoggyDay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3135317/foggyday)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871234/alarmmanager-doesnt-update-push-notification-time-hours-and-minutes-after-the#comment44145347_27871234), I've solved my problem: since the push notification was built only the first time into the onCreate() method, it's obvious that its time never changed. I've also used a deprecated way to build push notifications, but the problem was not caused by this. 
 So my code may be changed in two ways: 
 1) in this (deprecated) way:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    NotificationManager NM;
    Notification notify;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");

        NM=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notify=new Notification(android.R.drawable.
                stat_notify_more,"Notification",System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent pending=PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(),0, new Intent(),0);
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        notify.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notify.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),"Title","Body",pending);
        NM.notify(0, notify);
    }
}
```

2) ...and in this (better) way:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    NotificationManager NM;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentInfo("Ciao!")
                .setSubText("Hey!")
                .setTicker("Hoy!")
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is a good practice to leave the onCreate() method empty, but it works :D however, I accept other suggestions about it